# JOIN com dois campos na clausula ON com CodeIgniter (mysql+php) (MVC)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join, chave-composta

Estou precisando de ajuda com CodeIgniter. "Caiu no meu colo" aplicação legada.
Abaixo está uma tentativa minha de ilustrar o problema, ou seja, nomes de tabelas e campos são "cenograficos".

Como fazer um join ?

Preciso listar a relação de nomes de cargos e códigos  dependendo da empresa e departamento selecionado em uma view,

```
Tabela de cargo: 
    codigo (pk), Nome

Tabela de CargosPorEmpresa: 
    id (pk), IdEmpresa(fk, idDepartamento(Fk), ramal, localizacao....
```

```php
$this->db->select('cargo.Nome,cargo.Codigo', false) ;
$this->db->join('cargo',[(cargo.idEmpresa = $_POST['idEmpresa']),
                         (cargo.idDepartamento = $_POST['idDepartamento']),'');

$this->db->where('cargosPorEmpresa.idEmpresa' , $_POST['idEmpresa']);
$this->db->where('cargosPorEmpresa.idDepartamento' , $_POST['idDepartamento']);
$this->db->order_by('cargo.Nome ASC');
$this->db->group_by('cargo.Nome,cargo.Codigo');
$query = $this->db->get('cargosPorEmpresa');
```

Answer (score 0):

tenta dessa forma, não pode ter um where em um join

```
return $this->db->select("cargo.Nome, cargo.Codigo", false)
        ->from(cargosPorEmpresa)
        ->join('cargo', 'cargo.idEmpresa = cargosPorEmpresa.idEmpresa')
        ->where('cargosPorEmpresa.idEmpresa' , $_POST['idEmpresa'])
        ->where('cargosPorEmpresa.idDepartamento' , $_POST['idDepartamento'])
        ->order_by('cargo.Nome ASC')
        ->group_by('cargo.Nome,cargo.Codigo')->get();;
```